# Understanding pointers in C using example code

Tags: c, pointers

I am learning pointers in C, so I am looking at one example. I tried to add comments to understand what is going on. Is the following code correct? In other words, do my comments describe the operation correctly?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

    int x, y;
    int *p1, *p2;

    x=-42;
    y=163;

    p1=&x; //pointer 1 points to the address of x
    p2=&y; //pointer 2 points to the address of y

    *p1=17; //this just made x=17 because it says that the value at the address where p1 points should be 17
    p1=p2; //this just made pointer 1 point at the same place as pointer 2, which means that p1 now points at y

    p2=&x; //this just made pointer 2 point at the address of x

    //NOW WE HAVE: p1 points at y, p2 points at x, y=17 because of p1

    *p1=*p2; //now x=17 as well as y (because the value at the place p2 points, which is x, just became 17)

    printf("x=%d, \ny=%d\n", x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you run this program and view how variables change in a debugger, can you see if the observed behaviour matches with your comments? I'd say so, but you should use available tools that will help you to confirm what you say in the comments.

Comment: yes your comments are correct

Comment: The only thing you may have misunderstood is the last line `*p1=*p2;` because that is setting `y` to `17`. It's hard to tell from your comment on that line what you meant. Otherwise everything you wrote is accurate.

Comment: always always learn to use your debugger, good point @mcleod_ideafix

Comment: You might have better luck with such similar questions on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *"NOW WE HAVE: ... y=17"* No, at that point y is still 163.

Comment: Yes, I just see that I made a mistae there @Beta. Thank you all for your comments and a suggestion to use codereview.stackexchange.com. I didn't know about it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Check the debugger", for sure.  You can also just copy your printf statement after each time you set a value to check, since you're just learning, but this isn't good long-term practice.

I'm not sure if you've quite got the concept and just made a typo mixing up x and y, or if you're making an incorrect assumption, but yes, in your comments:

> //NOW WE HAVE: p1 points at y, p2 points at x, y=17 because of p1

you have the location of p1 and p2 correct at this point, but y has not received an assignment since you gave it the value of 163 initially.  Assignments to *p1 will affect y, but only after the p1=p2 line.
At the point of this comment, x=17, because of the *p1=17 line a few line up.  y is unchanged from the initial assignment.

> *p1=*p2; //now x=17 as well as y (because the value at the place p2 points, which is x, just became 17)

y becomes 17 here, as *p1 (which is now y) is assigned the value in *p2, which, as you state, is x.